# bash while string is not empty

Tags: linux, string, bash

I'm trying to set up a script that parses a string.

My loop is currently

```
while [ -n "$RAW" ]; do
    // do some processing here
    RAW=$(echo $RAW| sed -r 's/^.{15}//')
done
```

However, the script never seems to end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not ending because the `sed` expression is not correct. It expects minimum 15 characters and does not work for anything less than 15 chars. Try this:

```
RAW=$(echo $RAW| sed -r 's/^.{0,15}//')
```

Comment: +1. @user1772510, in bash, you should replace `//` to `#`. Second, the sed command didn't work properly, so RAW is never changed, that's why it goes infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want this:

```
#!/bin/bash
RAW=012345678901234567890
.
.
.
RAW=${RAW:15}
echo $RAW
567890
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not end because of the logic inside your while loop.

You're doing to overwrite variable `RAW`:

```
RAW=$(echo $RAW| sed -r 's/^.{15}//')
```

Which means match and replace first 15 characters in original variable by empty string. What is there are only 10 characters left. In that sed won't match (and replace) and your varialbe `RAW` will remain at that value.

You probably want **upto 15 characters from start** to be replaced and if that's the case this is what you will need:

```
RAW=$(echo $RAW | sed -r 's/^.{1,15}//')
```